# Holt-Winters optimal parameters with gradient descent

Tags: time-series, forecasting, gradient-descent

Can we use gradient descent in order to find optimal alpha, beta and gamma for Holt-Winters model?
And more generally, are there any academic works that suggest methods for finding optimal values for those parameters?

Comment: Finding optimal parameters using optimization methods for holts winters has been around for many many decades. You could use any nonlinear optimization methods including gradient descent, sequential quadratic programming etc., any text book on time series forecasting software or book would carry appropriate numerical optimization method for HW technique

Answer (score 0):

Be carefull! In general, the gradient descent technique may be trapped in local optima if the problem being solved is not convex. Rather, you should use a global optimization technique such as Genetic Algorithms, PSO algorithms, Estimation of Distribution Algorithms, etc.